# Approaching JSON data returns 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

When I accessing "dept_name", the JSON returns 'undefined'.
How can I return correct output?

JSON object (content) from an API

```
"departments": [
      {
        "dept_no": "d005",
        "dept_name": "Development",
        "from_date": "1994-07-03",
        "to_date": "9999-01-01",
        "dept_manager": [
          {
            "emp_no": 110511,
            "first_name": "DeForest",
            "last_name": "Hagimont",
            "email": "110511@cloud-spartan.com",
            "from_date": "1985-01-01",
            "to_date": "1992-04-25"
          },
          {
            "emp_no": 110567,
            "first_name": "Leon",
            "last_name": "DasSarma",
            "email": "110567@cloud-spartan.com",
            "from_date": "1992-04-25",
            "to_date": "9999-01-01"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

when I accessing data['departments'].dept_no returns 'undefined'

```
      var content_depart = content['departments'];
      console.log(content_depart);
      var department = content_depart.dept_name;
      console.log(department);
```

console.log(content_depart)

```
[ { dept_no: 'd005',
    dept_name: 'Development',
    from_date: '1994-07-03',
    to_date: '9999-01-01',
    dept_manager: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

console.log(department)

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['departments']` is an **array**.

```
let data =
{ //               v--------- array !
    "departments": [
    { // ...
```

You can't access its members directly, but have to specify the index first. In example :

```js
let data = {"departments":[{"dept_no":"d005","dept_name":"Development","from_date":"1994-07-03","to_date":"9999-01-01","dept_manager":[{"emp_no":110511,"first_name":"DeForest","last_name":"Hagimont","email":"110511@cloud-spartan.com","from_date":"1985-01-01","to_date":"1992-04-25"},{"emp_no":110567,"first_name":"Leon","last_name":"DasSarma","email":"110567@cloud-spartan.com","from_date":"1992-04-25","to_date":"9999-01-01"}]}]};
    
console.log(data.departments[0].dept_no);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed a small part haha

Answer (score 0):

Add index before accessing data

```
      var department = content_depart[0].dept_name;
      console.log(department);
```

Answer (score 0):

`content_depart` is array not an object

so go with `content_depart[0].dept_name`